# Calculation of the sum of matrices in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I am thinking about problem. How to count in R

[image: Image of LaTeX equation]

(A-square matrix,k-any natural number) WITHOUT "for"?

Comment: Do you mean the trace of the matrix, that would be possible using the following link https://rpubs.com/aaronsc32/matrix-trace, which uses `sum(diag(A))` to calculate the trace of the square matrix A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've interpreted your notation correctly, perhaps something like this in base R...

```
A <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow = 2)                         #example matrix

k <- 10

B <- Reduce(`%*%`, (rep(list(A), k)), accumulate = TRUE)  #list of A^(1:k)

BB <- lapply(1:k, function(k) B[[k]]/k)                   #list of A^(1:k)/k

Reduce(`+`, BB)                                           #sum of series BB

         [,1]    [,2]
[1,] 603684.8 1319741
[2,] 879827.1 1923425
```